# SQL Server: Get date ranges of first and second week of a month

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to get the dates of first week of a month when GETDATE() is given as an input.

I can get the dates of current week by below code:-

```
select  
    convert(varchar(50), dateadd(dd, - datepart(dw, GETDATE()) + 1, GETDATE()), 101),
    convert(varchar(50), dateadd(dd, - datepart(dw, GETDATE()) + 7, GETDATE()), 101)
```

How can I get the dates for first, second week of the month based on `GETDATE()` as an input?

For example:

- 1 week working dates of July, 2016:- 1/7/2016 - 2/7/16
- 2 week working dates :- 4/7/2016 - 9/7/2016

Thanks

EDIT:-
I am using below query to get start and end date of each week for a given month:-

```
DECLARE @date date = '2016-07-08'--sample date
DECLARE @firstDay date = DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(M, 0, @date), 0)
DECLARE @firstWeekLastDay date = DATEADD(D, 7-DATEPART(DW, @firstDay), @firstDay)
DECLARE @secondWeekFirstDay date = DATEADD(D, 2, @firstWeekLastDay)
DECLARE @secondWeekLastDay date = DATEADD(D, 5, @secondWeekFirstDay)
DECLARE @thirdWeekfirstDay date = DATEADD(D, 2, @secondWeekLastDay)
DECLARE @thirdWeekLastDay date = DATEADD(D, 5, @thirdWeekfirstDay)
DECLARE @fourthWeekFirstDay date = DATEADD(D, 2, @thirdWeekLastDay)
DECLARE @fourthWeekLastDay date = DATEADD(D, 5, @fourthWeekFirstDay)
DECLARE @fifthWeekFirstDay date = DATEADD(D, 2, @fourthWeekLastDay)
DECLARE @fifthWeekLastDay date = DATEADD(D, 5, @fifthWeekFirstDay)

SELECT @firstDay, @firstWeekLastDay, @secondWeekFirstDay, @secondWeekLastDay, @thirdWeekfirstDay, @thirdWeekLastDay, @fourthWeekFirstDay, @fourthWeekLastDay
```

Comment: so the week starts at Sunday and ends at Saturday in that case?

Comment: also in the example 2week has only 6 days?

Comment: Yea so basically get all the dates which lies in first week for a specific month.

Comment: but there is mistake in example... how can week have 6 days..

Comment: So I only need working days from Monday- Saturday. Sorry I should have cleared that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get range using following query:

```
DECLARE @date date = '2016-07-08'--sample date
DECLARE @firstDay date = DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(M, 0, @date), 0)

SELECT CASE DATEPART(DW, @firstDay)
       WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(D, 1, @firstDay)
       ELSE @firstDay END D1,
       DATEADD(D, 7-DATEPART(DW, @firstDay), @firstDay) D2
```

You can also calculate first sunday of month:

```
DECLARE @date date = '2016-08-01'
DECLARE @firstDayOfMonth date = DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(M, 0, @date), 0)
DECLARE @firstSundayOfMonth date = DATEADD(D, (DATEDIFF(D, '2016-08-07', @firstDayOfMonth))/7*7, '2016-08-07')
```

First week would be from `1` to `sunday-1`, second - from `sunday+1` to `sunday+6`.

Comment: Thanks! I have altered query(Check Edit section ) to get each start and end dates for a specific month .

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all the dates of 1st and 2nd week of the month except Sundays based on GETDATE(). If you want to test for specific date just change the value of @date variable.

```
DECLARE @dt1 Datetime, @dt2 Datetime
DECLARE @date Datetime = GETDATE()

SELECT @dt1 = DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @date), 0) 
SELECT @dt2 = DATEADD(DD,14 , @dt1 )

;WITH daterange 
AS 
(
    SELECT [dates]=@dt1 ,
          DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @dt1) WD, --Weekday
          DATEPART(DD,@dt1) [DAY], -- Day
          1 WN -- Week no.
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [dates] + 1 , 
         DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [dates] + 1) WD, --Weekday
         DATEPART(DD,[dates] + 1) [DAY],  --Day
         CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [dates] + 1) = 1 AND [DAY]<>1 THEN WN + 1 ELSE WN END WN  --Week no.
    FROM   daterange 
    WHERE  [dates] + 1<= @dt2
) 
SELECT [dates]
FROM   daterange C
WHERE WN <= 2 AND WD <> 1
```